# mysql fulltext search reindex

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

on a web application we us fulltext index on a specific table.
It works pretty well, but the problem started when we need to modify the default min lenght of the word searched (from 4 letters, the default, to 3 letters).

We did it with these setup on the conf:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_ft_min_token_size = 3
ft_min_word_len = 3
```

and then we have rebotted the mysql, e recreated the index (we have tried several in order to recreate the index, also drop them and create by new).

But nothing works, word with 3 letters are never recognized by the query).

The query for example is:

```
select * from TABLE where MATCH(BLABLA) AGAINST ('+MADE* +INF*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

This return all the string with:

made infaaaa
made infbbbb

but not return the string with just "made inf" and nothing more.

What is the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Ok solved...make sure that the word that you are seeking is not included on the mysql built in stop words...https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html